# How to backup all the files that I'm copying before being overwritten?

Tags: backup, cp, file-copy

I have a folder like this:

```
./folder-a/index.html
./folder-b/index.html
./folder-c/subdir/index.html
./new-content/folder-a/index.html
./new-content/folder-b/index.html
./new-content/folder-c/subdir/index.html
```

The `new-content` folder contains an on-going updated stuff that I update. When I want to update my content I am going to copy them to overwrite the existed ones, like this:

`\cp -rf new-content/* ./`

But how can I set up a backup of the going-to-be-overwritten files?

Any simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `man cp` (the GNU version, found on Linux and Cygwin)

> --backup[=CONTROL]
>
> make a backup of each existing destination file
>
> -b     like --backup but does not accept an argument

Example

```
touch 1 2
cp -bv 2 1
‘2’ -> ‘1’ (backup: ‘1~’)
```

Note that this does not check for existing backup files, i.e. if `1~` exists it will be overwritten. Using the long version you can avoid this. E.g.

```
cp -v --backup=numbered 2 1
‘2’ -> ‘1’ (backup: ‘1.~1~’)
cp -v --backup=numbered 2 1
‘2’ -> ‘1’ (backup: ‘1.~2~’)
cp -v --backup=numbered 2 1
‘2’ -> ‘1’ (backup: ‘1.~3~’)
```